# High cpu use by hhvm whenever run apache benchmark

Tags: apache, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, benchmarking, hhvm

When I execute Apache Benchmark for testing traffic load on my website.. The cpu of my server getting 100% used by HHVM.

```
 **ab -kc 200 -n 1000 http://searchpan.in/**

root@K10:~# ab -kc 200 -n 1000 http://searchpan.in/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1528965 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking searchpan.in (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Completed 600 requests
Completed 700 requests
Completed 800 requests
Completed 900 requests
Completed 1000 requests
Finished 1000 requests


Server Software:        nginx/1.8.0
Server Hostname:        searchpan.in
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /
```

[**check screenshot of apacheBenchmark test**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gki4H.jpg)

Here the CPU Status when running benchmark

```
top - 10:20:42 up 1 day, 15:13,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.02, 0.08
Tasks:  87 total,   1 running,  86 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 45.1 us, 10.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 43.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   2049956 total,  1283576 used,   766380 free,   210272 buffers
KiB Swap:  2047996 total,        0 used,  2047996 free.   684304 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
13140 www-data  20   0 1140488 275236 105660 S 100.0 13.4   3:32.55 hhvm
 1078 mysql     20   0  821220  65436   7512 S   8.6  3.2   9:22.43 mysqld
13118 www-data  20   0  103104   4476   1048 S   1.7  0.2   0:03.05 nginx
13572 root      20   0   37636   3464   1880 S   1.0  0.2   0:00.03 ab
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.7  0.0   1:05.58 rcu_sched
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:28.42 rcuos/0
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:28.54 rcuos/1
    1 root      20   0   33484   2852   1468 S   0.0  0.1   0:01.84 init
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.22 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:+
   10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
   11 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuob/0
   12 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuob/1
   13 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.47 migration/0
   14 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.05 watchdog/0
   15 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.20 watchdog/1
```

[**screenshot HHVM uses High CPU more than 100%**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh3uE.jpg)

### My question is.. How to configure HHVM and Nginx for high traffic load ?

Server :
Digitalocean,
1GB RAM,
2 core cpu,
Ubuntu 14.04,
Nginx 1.8.0